# Different proof that $\overline{A\cup B}\subset \overline{A}\cup \overline{B}$

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, alternative-proof

As Paul Erdos once said, first find a proof that works, and then go looking for the beautiful proof.

Before looking at the proof my textbook gives for $\overline{A\cup B}\subset \overline{A} \cup \overline{B}$, I attempted something myself. What I did is nothing like the proof given in the text, and might be needlessly complicated, but I wanted to check that it still works. I don't always trust my judgment that the mathematical logic is correct, so sometimes an extra set of eyes is useful.

First, perhaps I should define $\overline{A}$. It is the set of **adherence points** of the set $A\subset X$ meaning it is the set of all points $x\in X$ such that any neighborhood of $x$ also contains points of $A$.

Now, here is my proof:

> Suppose $x\notin \overline{A}\cup \overline{B}$. Then, $x\notin \overline{A}$ and $x\notin \overline{B}$.
>
> $x\notin \overline{A}$ implies that $\exists$ neighborhood $U(x)$ such that $x \in U(x)$ and $U(x) \cap A =\emptyset$, which implies that $x\in A^{c}$.
>
> Likewise, $x\notin \overline{B}$ means that $\exists$ a neighborhood $W(x)$ such that $x\in W(x)$ and $W(x)\cap B = \emptyset$. This implies that $x\in B^{c}$.
>
> So, $x\in A^{c}$ and $x\in B^{c}$, which means that $x \in A^{c}\cap B^{c}\subset\overline{A^{c}\cap B^{c}}\, \implies \, x\notin \overline{A\cup B}$

So, I showed that $x\notin \overline{A}\cup \overline{B}\, \implies \, x\notin \overline{A \cup B}$, which is the contrapositive of $x\in \overline{A \cup B}\, \implies \, x\in \overline{A} \cup \overline{B}$, at least I think it is. I've experienced some setbacks as of late that have caused me to lose a little bit of confidence in my judgment when it comes to mathematical logic.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does $x \in \overline {A^c \cap B^c} \implies x \not \in \overline{A \cup B}$?

Comment: @fleablood don't worry about it. The question's been answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof sets itself up well, but then ends confusedly. In particular, you first note:

> If $x\not \in \bar A$, then there is an open set $U$ containing $x$ disjoint from $A$.

and similarly

> If $x\not \in \bar B$, then there is an open set $W$ containing $x$ disjoint from $B$.

But then you do not use these premises and merely claim that since $x$ is in $\overline{A^C\cap B^C}$ it must not be in $\overline{A\cup B}$. This is not a valid argument - these two sets intersect exactly on the boundary of $A\cup B$.

Rather, to conclude that $x\not \in \overline{A\cup B}$, you need to show there is an open set $V$ containing $x$ disjoint from $A\cup B$. This is easy given what you showed earlier: Just take $V=U\cap W$.

Comment: thanks! I think I was confusing $\overline{(A\cup B)^{c}}$ with $(\overline{A\cup B})^{c}$.

Comment: @ALannister This proof from the contrapositive (in Milo's corrected version) is I think essentially the proof a textbook will give, I think.

Comment: @HenroBrandsma it's not the one mine gives, though. This is the proof it gives: "Since $\overline{A}$ and $\overline{B}$ are closed, and the finite union of closed sets a closed, $\overline{A}\cup \overline{B}$ is closed. Moreover, $\overline{A}$ contains $A$ and $\overline{B}$ contains $B$, so $A\cup B \subset \overline{A} \cup \overline{B}$ however, the smallest closed set that contains $A\cup B$ is $\overline{A\cup B}$. So, $\overline{A\cup B} \subset \overline{A} \cup \overline{B}$." I didn't think to do it this way though when I was trying it by myself.

Comment: @ALannister in your textbook they're using things beyond the definition. I imagine that if they'd prove it right after the definition, the proof would be like yours. But in your book they presumably already showed that the closure is the minimal closed set, and then the proof given uses that instead of the definition.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma yes, I probably should have mentioned in my post that those things had already been proven in the text beforehand.

Comment: @MiloBrandt can you please take a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2179730/strongly-equivalent-metrics-induce-equivalent-topologies-trouble-with-radii-of ? I'm stuck and I'm having trouble figuring out how to move forward from there. Thank you! :)